# Problem with use of Axios mock adapter GET

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I try to use Axios mock adapter to simulate GET to Web API, but it does not work.

The api url looks like something like that :

```
`/api/forms/${guid}`
```

I try using Regex, but doesn't work (probably something with the d+):

```
mock.onGet('/\/api\/forms\/\d+/').reply((config) => {
    // the actual id can be grabbed from config.url
    console.log(config);
    return [200, {}];
});
```

This work:

```
mock.onGet('/users').reply((config) => {
    // the actual id can be grabbed from config.url
    console.log(config);
    return [200, {}];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex should not be quoted in JavaScript.

Try this:

```js
mock.onGet(/\/api\/forms\/\d+/).reply((config) => {
```

Comment: God bless! Left over of test I did before.